# Swiper angular not working when rendered inside ng-content of a generic component

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I am trying to create a generic component which is intended to make the styling in the project similar. Each page has image slider as well as content data. When i try to do that, the swiper is not functional. An example to make it clear:

The following is the generic styling component which has the requisite styling:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-content">
    <ng-content select=".images"> </ng-content>
  </div>  
</div>
```

It is used in another page like:

```
<app-generic-component>
  <div class="images">
    <swiper [config]="config">
      <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let img of images">
       <img [src]="img"/>       
      </ng-template>
    </swiper>
  </div>
</app-generic-component>
```

Swiper does not work as it should. It works perfectly fine if it is not wrapped inside the generic component. If someone knows how to make it working, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Please add the code of swiper component.

Comment: do you mean the config. If that is the case, it is                                              
   config: SwiperOptions = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    effect: 'fade',
    navigation: true,
    loop: true
    virtual: true,
    pagination: { clickable: true }
  }

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to treat template as dynamic content template, try this

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="images">
  <li>
    <img [src]="item"/>       
  </li>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work for me